# Do cassandra contact nodes act as proxies

Tags: cassandra

I am using a very large cluster with hundreds of nodes. I only specify several nodes as contact points. My question is, do I have to open a firewall to all of the cluster's nodes, or can I only open to the contact nodes? Meaning, does all my communication go through the contact nodes as proxies, or does the Cassandra driver contact the non-contact nodes directly?